# How are @Configuration classes validated automatically on Start Up of Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a class named MyConfig.java.

```
    import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

    @Configuration
    public class MyConfig {
       @NotNull
       @Value("${test.key}")
        public String queryIndex;
     }
```

My question is, how is it getting validated on the StartUp of Spring Boot application without any @Validated or @Valid. I Understand @Configuration classes are picked up by Spring container on Startup (to generate bean definitions if any) and javax.validator is on classpath.

The below code snippet makes sense because added @Valid annotation on POJO class :

```
    @PostMapping
    public String test(@Valid @RequestBody Employee emp) {
        
        return "";
    }
```

**From Spring Doc:-**

[Link Here for reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.14.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#validation-beanvalidation)

**3.8.1. Overview of the JSR-303 Bean Validation API**

JSR-303 standardizes validation constraint declaration and metadata for the Java platform. Using this API, you annotate domain model properties with declarative validation constraints and the runtime enforces them.

Comment: You can write aspect or BeanPostProccessor with the checking logic

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:-

MyConfig.java

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

@Configuration
@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="test")
public class MyConfig {
    
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyConfig.class);
    private static final String MYNAME = MyConfig.class.getSimpleName();
    
    @NotBlank(message = "Key should not be empty")
    @Value("${test.key}")
    public String test;

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }
   }
```

application.properties

```
server.port=5555
test.key=
test.name=
```

This dependency is a must in **pom.xml**

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
     <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
  </dependency>
```

So, **@Validated, @ConfigurationProperties** combined with **javax.validation** constraints are working behind the scenes.

**Error Description:-**

Binding to target org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException:
Failed to bind properties under 'test' to com.cgi.demo.MyConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3dcd81ec failed:

```
Property: test.test
Value: 
Reason: Key should not be empty
```

**For your reference from SprinBoot Doc's:-**

[Click Here for more info](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-validation)

**2.7.9. @ConfigurationProperties Validation**

Spring Boot attempts to validate **@ConfigurationProperties** classes whenever they are annotated with Spring’s **@Validated** annotation. You can use JSR-303 javax.validation constraint annotations directly on your configuration class. To do so, ensure that a compliant JSR-303 implementation is on your classpath and then add constraint annotations to your fields.